# Двойной SHA256 заголовка блока биткоина выдает не тот результат

Tags: c#, хеширование, sha256

Хэширую заголовок блока биткоина двойным SHA256, выдает не тот результат.
В чем ошибка, как реализовать?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace HashHeaderBlock
{
    class Program
    {   
        // Хэширование блока SHA256
        public static string HeaderBlockSha256(string headerBlock)
        {
            byte[] bytes = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(headerBlock);
            SHA256 blockSHA256 = new SHA256Managed();
            byte[] byteSHA = blockSHA256.ComputeHash(bytes);
            string hashBlock = BitConverter.ToString(byteSHA);
            hashBlock = hashBlock.ToLower().Replace("-", string.Empty);

            return hashBlock;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Заголовок блока на высоте 601562 https://www.blockchain.com/btc/block/601562
            string headerBlock = "000040202fb7b62ec0b6dd2f7bb775175f2715e7448a2834a2a406000000000000000000b8e50188424ea7a925e4684f13a1399636ddd8c41bb868068e36a53d560cc62d5EABB85DDF8E14174CF568B6";

            // Первое хэширование
            string firstSHA256 = HeaderBlockSha256(headerBlock);

            // Второе хэширование
            string secondSHA256 = HeaderBlockSha256(firstSHA256);

            Console.WriteLine(secondSHA256);

            // Получается         499db99e01805684078e149f1243d8b5125e10b5d5e63d9704d89e2ad82f6a38
            // Должно получиться  8e1836f7358f479476546d509ecb478e5d3243d712760d000000000000000000
            // или                0000000000000000000d7612d743325d8e47cb9e506d547694478f35f736188e
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хэш надо из байт HEX-строки вычислять, а не из самой строки

```
public static string HeaderBlockSha256(string headerBlock)
{
    byte[] bytes = Convert.FromHexString(headerBlock);
    byte[] hash = SHA256.HashData(bytes);
    return Convert.ToHexString(hash).ToLower();
}
```

```
8e1836f7358f479476546d509ecb478e5d3243d712760d000000000000000000
```

Можно кстати сразу двойной считать, так быстрее будет

```
public static string HeaderBlockDoubleSha256(string headerBlock)
{
    byte[] bytes = Convert.FromHexString(headerBlock);
    byte[] hash = SHA256.HashData(SHA256.HashData(bytes));
    return Convert.ToHexString(hash).ToLower();
}
```

Comment: а зачем хэш от хэша брать?

Comment: @Grundy в исходном коде автора так сделано, он просто дважды через строку прогоняет, я предложил залпом)

Comment: @Grundy в биткоине используется двойное хэширование